# Authorize attribute redirects to LoginPath instead of AccessDeniedPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization

I have the following configuration for the application cookie:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/LogIn";
    options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/LogOut";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = $"";
});
```

And also the following authorization policies:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("User", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
});
```

Upon user creation I add the following policy:

```
await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, new[] {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User")});
```

Then I have a dummy action with authorize attribute with Admin policy, whenever I attempt to access it with an account that has only the 'User' policy, I expect to be redirected to AccessDeniedPath since I'm already logged in and whenever I'm not logged in I expect to be redirected to LoginPath, however I'm always redirected to LoginPath.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Action()
{
    //..
}
```

So to put it short, the desired behavior is so that I get redirected to `options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/LogIn"` whenever the user attempts to access resource without being logged in and get redirected to `options.AccessDeniedPath = $"";` whenever the user is logged in but has insufficient privileges.

I intend to apply this same idea not only to controllers but to razor pages too.

Comment: Do you mean that even user has logged in , when access protected admin controller , user will be redirect to `/Identity/LogIn` ?

Comment: @NanYu yes this is the current behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Authorize` attribute returns error 401, and that will usually redirect to login with the correct credentials. The `AccessDeniedPath` is used when handling error 403, I believe.

We recently implemented a custom authorization attribute specifically to handle separation of 401 and 403 errors.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //If user is authenticated, send a 403 instead of 401
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);//403
        }
        else
        {
            //if user is not authenticated, throw 401
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext); //401
        }
    }        
}
```